# Python + VSCode not playing nice with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I regularly use python on my PC (Spyder, Juptyer etc) without issue.  I've recently installed VSCode, to take advantage of its debug features.

However, I can't seem to get it to play nice with Numpy.  Running a script simply with:

```
import numpy as np


Exception has occurred: ImportError

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"
```

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

Also:
[image]
[image]

I have these installed and enabled:

[image]

This works in Spyder, Jupyter etc.  And I'm using the 'base' conda environment, and can see that numpy is installed in the Packages list.

Any help on fixing this (so I can debug without using 1000x prints!) is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the URL mentioned in the error message? There seems to be a frequently reported issue with vscode and anaconda.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make my way through it, but I'm not really an environments / conda expert so it might be staring me in the face.

Comment: It used to be that building C extensions on ms-windows was a real PITA because of issues with the microsoft compiler and runtime. One of the main features of Anaconda was was sparing ms-windows users this misery. That issue has been sorted, and the main attraction of Anaconda has now vanished, IMO. So these days I just advise people to use python from `python.org` and get modules from `pypi`.

Comment: yeaaaaa. I understood like, half of that?  lol.  Anaconda is a nice 'click, download'

Comment: Point is, things are simple until they aren't. And then you are in trouble. :-/ Because now you have to figure out if the problem is with python, numpy, conda or vscode.

Comment: For future reference, IDE's like vscode tend to have issues with code that uses `multiprocessing` or `subprocess`. In that case, run your script with plain python from a `cmd` window first and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Oh the code has no issue, it works in Spyder, Jupyter etc.  Its just VSCode thats throwing the issue.

Comment: If you do not use the conda environment, can you run the code successfully by simply using Python ("ctrl+shift+P" and type "Python: select interpreter")? By the way, is conda environment activated?

Comment: I can run it all fine in Jupyter and Spyder if thats what you mean?  I've tried the two python interpreters that VSCode had listed out, but no luck..

Comment: Can you run files in CMD of windows? Because vscode is only an editor shell, it still uses the system terminal in essence